# How to query with Mongodb or Mongoose and print it with javascript?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I'm running node js server connected with mongoose to mongoDb. I want to know how to maque a query that returns to me all the objects of especific collection and print it on the website with a table. Anyone can help me?

Thnxs!!!

Comment: literally the first page of the mongoose site http://mongoosejs.com/

Answer (score -1):

Lets say your Collection name is Book
Then This would help:

```
Book.find().exec(function(err, books) {
        res.jsonp(books);
});
```

You can use this in your Route:

```
    app.route('/books')
    .get(books.list);
```

I think this could help you et up to speed [MEAN](http://meanjs.org/generator.html)
If I know more about what framework you are using I can help more

Comment: i'm using express framework, I only want to display de query result into the webpage, i mean, pass the returned stuff of the query to the client document to display it. thanks

Comment: the down vote it's note mine man, i will try your answer, thank you!

Comment: my route is /ranking, i want to retrieve all the user names of collection called Usersm thanks!

Comment: That line of code return the whole book Schema then in your client side you can show username by books.username
See, there is many thing you need to know and I really suggest you to take a look at that MEAN.js website it help you build a simple web
Then if you want to change it you need to learn more 
I suggest Books like: express js by Azat mardan